# Contracting the rational bar cocomplex for a finite group G

Tags: homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and define $B^p(G,\mathbb{Q}) = {\rm Functions}(G^p,\mathbb{Q})$. These $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces assemble into a cochain complex with differential
$$d \sigma(g_0,\dots,g_p) = \sigma(g_1,\dots,g_p) + \sum_i (-1)^i \sigma(g_0,\dots,g_{i-1} g_i,\dots,g_p) \pm\sigma(g_0,\dots,g_{p-1})$$ 
This complex has zero cohomology, so the identity map and the zero map are chain homotopic. Indeed, there are going to be lots of different chain homotopies between the identity map and the zero map.

> **Question:**  Is there a nice way to write down a chain homotopy $\psi^p : B^{p} \to B^{p-1}$? I know how to compute such a $\psi$ for any given $p$ using linear algebra, but I would like a formula which works in general if such a formula exists.

Comment: Doesn't $\psi(g_0,\ldots,g_p) = (1,g_0,\ldots,g_p)$ give you what you want?

Comment: I haven't checked, but I'd expect something like $\psi \sigma(g_0,\ldots,g_p) = \frac 1 {\vert G \vert} \sum_{g \in G} \sigma(g,g_0,\ldots,g_p)$ to work. What makes the complex acyclic is Maschke's theorem so a contracting homotopy should involve averaging over the group.